# Connect VB on Visual Studio to MS Access

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

What would be the code that will connect the Data from MS Access to the Visual Basic in Visual Studio? I am new to Visual Basic.

Comment: Use the wizards; they provide the basic requirements that you'll need.

Comment: Is it on Visual Studio? @Paul

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for the connection you can use this

```
 Dim con As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\database\data.mdb")
```

I place the data.mdb at custom folder name 'database' in the debug folder of the application.

Comment: If this answer is what you are looking for please mark this as an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is more detailed...

```
   Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

   con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\DBName.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

   Try
     con.Open()
   Catch ex As Exception
     MsgBox(ex.Message)
   End Try
```